# Is there a difference in the order of equality?

Tags: c#

Or in short, is the second operator needed?

```
    public static bool operator ==(Vector3 v, float scalar)
    {
        return v.X == scalar && v.Y == scalar && v.Z == scalar;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(float scalar, Vector3 v)
    {
        return v == scalar;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is needed if you want to allow asymmetric equality tests:

```
bool foo = (yourVector3 == 5);    // requires the first version
bool bar = (5 == yourVector3);    // requires the second version
```

Without the first version you'd get a compile-time error saying something like *"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'int'"*. Without the second version the error would say something like *"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Vector3'"*.

Comment: Strange. Now, may I ask, why isn't this built-in?

Answer (score 2):

There is from the developer's expectation that equality is commutative  e.g. if you do a == b that b==a is also valid. Because of this it would be confusing if you did one and it worked and then reversed it and you got the following error.

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'Vector3'

But strictly speaking no you don't have to. It would just smell really bad.